# Is it possible to mark text for further folding/unfolding with side button after unfolding it?

Tags: sublimetext3, folding

After I unfold the area of text which I folded it cant be again fold with side button because it disappears, can it stay there so I can again fold it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fold arrows that Sublime adds to the gutter only appear based on the indentation of your code; specifically there needs to be at least two lines below a line that are both indented (how much indent doesn't matter as long as there is any) for that line to gain a fold arrow.

As visualized in your screen shots, there is no indent and so you're forced to use manual key bindings in order to fold code.

Comment: Does sublime support feature not to unfold all nested fold? Like explained there: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/nested-fold-all/29503